# How to get the object in a vscode extension?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

When developing a new extension for Visual Studio Code, how can I get the current class where my cursor is pointed to?

For example:

```
export class MyClassA {

  parameter1: number = 5;

  myFunc() {
    return parameter1 * 2;
  }

}

export class MyClassB {
   anotherParamenter = null;
}
```

If my cursor is located inside the `myFunc` scope and I call `registerHoverProvider` or whatever, I want to know that I'm inside the class `MyClassA`.

Is it possible to retrieve the object or only the cursor position?

Comment: I think you have to use one of the methods to extract text from the document (using the cursor position), and then use the symbol search api after doing some parsing to figure out the actual class data. Not sure though, seems like should be a better way, but this is how I've approached it in the past.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The context of text in a code editor is highly dependent of what language the code is in. You need a parser for the language to determine the syntactic and semantic details of the written code.

Hence, the first thing you have to do therefor is to implement a parser or use a parsing service provided by other tools. Once this is in place you can query that to find the syntactic context (e.g. `myFunc` in `MyClassA` in module `foo`) and then act on that to generate informations for your hover provider.